# Call python code from uWSGI master cycle

Tags: python, c, uwsgi

I have written a simple plugin for uWSGI.

```
#include <uwsgi.h>

static void cycle() {
      uwsgi_log("In master cycle\n");
}

struct uwsgi_plugin master_plugin = {
        .name = "master",
        .master_cycle = cycle,
};
```

Now I want to call some python code in master cycle thread in the same Python interpreter where my WSGI-application initialized. Is there uWSGI API for it? Can I use python plugin: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/plugins/python/python_plugin.c ? If possible, please, give me a snippet how to do it.

**UPDATE**

Some context from comments

1. I want to implement in-memory caching that utilizes copy-on-write feature, so I load data into master process and refork workers, then they all get fresh data.
2. I cannot use uWSGI cache because serialization/deserialization takes about 200ms and objects I cache are complex python objects such as SQLAlchemy model instances, actually a list of such instances. Sample list pickled with protocol 2 takes about 6Mb space.
3. I want to keep caching as simple as caching decorator, so cached methods do not care about being cached. This is for backward compatibility and for simplicity of adding cached methods in future.
4. I cannot afford to reload all workers at once with uwsgi.reload() for too reasons: 1) reforking all workers (20-30 process) may lead to performance impact for every period - instead I want to refork workers distributed in time (say every 5 seconds) 2) there may be several caches with different expire period full reload will invalidate them all at once and give unneeded load to database
5. Initially, I created a new thread in master process that periodically revalidates cache and sends HUP signal to workers for graceful refork. The problem is that there is no full control when worker will actually die and respawned, so it may fork while my thread in the middle of cache update and forked worker gets corrupted data. Is there a way to provide consistent data without thread synchronization
6. To solve problem above I want some code in master cycle that will check some semaphore with updating thread and suspend master cycle until cache update is over. That will guarantee no fork during cache update

Comment: Can you describe the specific use case ? Generally it is not a good idea to run "invasive" code (like CPython, expecially once the GIL is enabled) in the master_loop. Maybe there are easier solutions.

Comment: I want to create a specific in-memory cache, that utilizes copy-on-write feature. Literaly, I want master process periodically refresh cached values and gracefully refork all workers, so they get updated data, since they get the content of memory of master process after fork.

Comment: Why you do not use the uWSGI cache ? it has various operational modes and it is really fast. Btw if you prefer your original approach, just add a 'mule' to the stack dedicated to periodically reloading the stack (calling uwsgi.reload()) then instantiate your cache in a python module you can load in the master on startup with --shared-pyimport file

Comment: Thank you for answering. uWSGI cache requires object serialization/deserialization, correct me if I am wrong. I need to cache complex python objects such as SQLAlchemy model instances with their relations. So it takes too much time for deserialization and caching loses sense then. Reloading full stack at once is not a good option for me, because it would give performance impact. Instead I would reload each worker separately every ~5 secs. HUP signal works well for it. Also I have several caches with different expiration periods, so I need to keep them. I have 20-30 workers now.

Comment: Then spawn a python thread (remember to add --enable-threads) in the master (just use the shared import), you will get the same result as calling the code in the master cycle, but without the risk of destroying the master (well, obviously a bug in the python code will destroy the instance)

Comment: @DmitryMugtasimov Did you profile your code to make sure current caching (or serialization) is a bottleneck, and the only way to optimize it is to refork everything? Also usually what you want cached is processing result, not raw data. Of course I don't know the details, just the problem looks very uncommon.

Comment: @roberto I need some sync between python thread and master cycle to prevent worker respawn (fork) during cache update (while data is inconsistent state). Please, see number 5 and 6 in the UPDATE section of the question.

Comment: @jwalker My collegue did and I rechecked it now. Please, see number 2 in the UPDATE section. I need to cache "raw" data to save time for retrieving it from database and deserialization into SQLAlchemy  model instances.

Answer (score 1):

After having read your requirements, i think your best bet is the uWSGI 2.1 fork server feature:

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/master/ForkServer.rst

This shows how to use it with python (the feature was initially developed only for perl):

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/master/examples/CPythonForkServer.rst

and this thread contains some note about it

http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2014-June/007444.html

Basically you have two "unrelated" instances, one in which you constantly build your cache, and a second one forked from that one whenever you need.

Finally, if you really want to run custom python code in the master cycle this is a snippet from which you can start:

```
#include <uwsgi.h>
void PyRun_SimpleString(char *);

static void cycle() {
      uwsgi_log("In master cycle\n");
        PyRun_SimpleString("print \"aaa\"");
}

struct uwsgi_plugin master_plugin = {
        .name = "master",
        .master_cycle = cycle,
};
```

Comment: Thank you for support. Using the Emperor seems very complicated to me at first glance. I will consider it if I fail with injection into master cycle. Unfortunately, the snippet you gave me fails with **!!! uWSGI process 22531 got Segmentation Fault !!!** Do you have any ideas why? I build with $ uwsgi --build-plugin plugin/master.c 
*** uWSGI building and linking plugin from plugin/master.c ***
[x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] master_plugin.so
build time: 0 seconds
*** master plugin built and available in master_plugin.so ***

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6e7cd8d5546c0628a3cd4452973c9b72de7279ed/Doc/faq/extending.rst#how-can-i-execute-arbitrary-python-statements-from-c 

:c:func:`PyRun_SimpleString` takes a single string argument to be executed in the context of the module __main__

I'd rather need to use context of module where my WSGI application is imported: uwsgi --http :8003 --wsgi mymodule:application --honour-stdin --master --workers 1 --py-auto-reload=1 --plugin ./master_plugin.so
In my case it is module named "mymodule". Is there a way to get PyObject* pointer from uWSGI?

Comment: Just to be little more clear I created simple.py 

print 'IMPORTING'

def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return ['Hello World']

print 'IMPORTED'

Run as:
uwsgi --http :8003 --wsgi simple:application --honour-stdin --master --workers 2 --py-auto-reload=1

So how to execute python code in the context of module "simple"?

On the other hand all I need is to pass 1 bit of data from spawned thread into master cycle to make it wait until cache update is over, which will prevent it from forking in the middle with inconsistent cache

Comment: It looks like I need to get this object, but I wonder if I can get it from master cycle plugin https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/e45f710694f18052aa00ee5bb866d9aeca76fb80/plugins/python/pyloader.c#L162

Comment: Probably, it is easier to call C code from Python to set suspension bit which will be checked in master cycle. Until it is not zero, master cycle is suspended, so it can not fork.